# how to save results from ajax queries between pages

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, search

**Background Information**

I have a web application which includes a search page.  This search provides 3 different drop down boxes that are populated via ajax. 
When you first load the page, box 1 is populated with a list of default locations.
When the user selects a location, a second drop down appears on the same page and is populated via ajax with buildings within the selected location. 
Once a building is selected, a final drop down box with a list of rooms appear. 
Once the user selects a room, the page displays details about the room and the user can drill down into one of the room properties - which will take them to a new page.

**Problem Description**

When users have completed viewing the room details web page, and hit the "back" button, I would like to be able to show them where they last left off ... that is the search page with all their previous selections that led them to the room details.  Currently, when they hit the back button, the default search page loads and their previous selections disappear.

What's the best way to persist the details of their search request?
I was thinking of adding values to the URL ... like a query string.  Right now, the URL of course doesn't change because everything is done via ajax / javascript for the search page.
But aside from this option, I was wondering if there's another idea / way to accomplish the same thing.

The solution has to work across all browsers including IE, Chrome, FFox, Safari.

**Code**

ajax code that's triggered when they change values in drop downs:

```
 $('#Locations').live('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo site_url('mycontroller/getbuildings/');?>" + "/" + $selectedvalue,
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(returnDataFromController) {

             logic to populate building drop down
        }


 $('#buiding_Locations').live('change',function(){
     $('#room_locations').html('');
     $('#search').hide();
      var htmlstring;
      $selectedvaluebranch_ = $('#Locations').val();
      $selectedvaluebuiding_ = $('#buiding_Locations').val();

      $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo site_url('mycontroller/getrooms');?>" + "/" + $selectedvaluebuiding_,
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(returnDataFromController) {
                    logic to populate room list
                }
```

In the method that fills in the Locations drop down,(mycontroller/getLocations) I've added logic to use / check for session variables... and now when I click on the back button, the location selection is saved.  The "mycontroller/getLcations" method is the default method that is called when the search page is loaded.

But I'm wondering about the best way to get the other two drop down boxes to be populated. As you can see, they are populated only when the user changes the values of the "parent" drop down box.

Perhaps I need to create another method in my controller that does the query for all 3 boxes.. and sends all that data to the front end instead of the way I'm doing it now...with 3 separate calls to 3 separate methods. 
And then I'll need to move out the logic that populates the individual drop down boxes out from where they are now to a re-useable function that can be called either when user makes a new selection, or when i'm trying to use the search data in session variables.

If there is a simpler way to do this, please let me know.  I'm just trying to make sure that I'm not unnecessarily writing additional code / that I'm refactoring properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, at each AJAX call to load the new dropdown, store a session variable indicating the state of the dropdowns. Then, just fetch those results to display the content you had previously selected.

---

Edit:

What you are doing seems quite allright. A few suggestions to make it better:

- You can get rid of the PHP tags in your jQuery by creating a javascript variable ( as `var mainURL = <?=site_url() ?>;`. This will allow then to put your functions in a file, that can be cached, hence you get a better separation between JS/PHP.
- For more flexibility, how about considering using POST instead of GET? This could allow to add a variable saying which form is being selected, and in the returning data, add a variable to indicate the field to populate: Therefore, you would only need one `$.ajax` instance.

For example, something like:

```
function updateForms(type,value){
 $.ajax({
      url:mainURL+"/mycontroller/getdata",
      type:"POST",
      data:{
            dropdownSelected:type,
            value:value
      },
      success:function(returnData){
            populate(returnData.form);
      });
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the suggestion re: sessions.  please see my comments under the new "Code" section I created in my post.

Comment: @dot I added some comments to your code in my post!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to use php session variables to store the last values that the user searched.

check out http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/ for a good example of how they are used.

**EDIT**

If on thing relies on another which relies on another and you have the smallest unit then u can backwards code your way backup. For instance you have the location saved as a session variable and that location can only be seen in the dropdown if X is selected and X can only be seen in that dropdown if Y is selected in another dropdown... etc etc. It sounds like you already have a parent-child relationship and if so then it should be easy to backwards code this.

Comment: plus 1 for the suggestion.  I've updated my question with additional details in the "Code" section of my post.